# PIG pass flatten as argument to udf

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I would like to flatten a relation and then pass it as argument. I tried this and it did not work:

> articles = load x using ...;
>
> groupedArticles = group articles ALL;
>
> result = foreach groupedArticles generate myUdfs.getResult(flatten(group))

thanks

Comment: group.* might do the trick for you here

Comment: sorry I did not get it

Comment: `result = foreach groupedArticles generate myUdfs.getResult(group.*)` You need to make sure though, that your UDF can handle what group.* throws at it. Might be better to call this manually like `getResult(group.$0, group.$1, ...)`